# Handling simple business process in MVC pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I'm using spring-mvc and my controllers mostly contain too much logic. When 3 - 5 service beans constitutes the business process and they are called in one handler, then there is some validation included and it results in a few if-else conditions with positive or negative response.

One possible solution is having a facade that contains all references to service beans and common interface of their methods. This makes it simpler, it can also constitute exception boundary in the MVC pattern, but still, the business process has some logic and validation and it is still dealt with in the handler method.

Should I create something like this? :

```
BusinessProcess {

processOrder() {
   serviceBeanA.call();
   result = serviceBeanB.call();
   validator.validate(result); // throw exception
   serviceBeanC.call(result);
 }
}
```

and use only BusinessProcess bean in my handlers ? Catching exceptions or return value would say what's wrong and what to include into the response. Otherwise content of processOrder method would be in handler.

Is it correct way ? How is this pattern called if so.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you should do as you suggest if I understood correctly. I don't think there's a name for this "pattern" nor needs to be. Since you seem uncertain, here's why I think you are thinking about the right thing.

Processing orders is an logical abstraction your handler is interested in. How the OrderProcessorBean (or BusinessProcessImpl) actually accomplishes this is an implementation detail and hidden from the handler/controller.

Not having such bean you may write a method processOrder in some controller and the controller has dependencies and references to service beans dealing with the details of processing orders. As you noticed this is not good design.

It also seems proper that the processing code lets exceptions fly out and is not bothered how they are handled by the caller. Perhaps a transaction is rolled back and perhaps some HTML containing error messages gets serviced to the end user, but the code (business logic) responsible for processing orders should not know that there are such things as Spring MVC or HTML.